# SwiftUI TextField with vertical axis does not align to firstTextBaseline when text is empty

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, text-alignment

I have a difficult time to find a workaround to align ***multiline*** `TextField` with another `Text` in `HStack`. I want to align it `firstTextBaseline`. The problem is, `TextField` jumps down when its text becomes empty and only the placeholder is shown.

I use these `HStack` in the `List` rows, but the alignment does not work even in the stripped and simplified code like this:

```
struct TextFieldAlignmentProblem: View {
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("1")
            TextField("Text", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: TextField jumps down when its text becomes empty and only the placeholder is shown.]

If I remove `axis: .vertical` or use `.center` alignment instead of `.firstTextBaseline`, the jumping problem disappears, but that is not the layout I need.

The problem looks quite simple, but I failed to find a suiting solution for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a bug that happens on the `axis: .vertical` when the field is empty.

#### ✅ Perfect Solution:

You can make a placeholder to hold the textfield in the correct position:

```
struct TextFieldAlignmentProblem: View {

    @State private var text: String = ""
    private var placeholder: String { text.isEmpty ? " " : text } //  Generate a correct placeholder. I have used a single space.

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text("1")

            TextField("Text", text: .constant(placeholder), axis: .vertical) //  Use the placeholder as the base
                .opacity(0) //  Make it hidden keeping the frame
                .overlay { //  Put the actual TextField on top of the placeholder view
                    TextField("Text", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

---

#### Simple Solution:

If you are not going to use different fonts, typefaces, dynamic types, etc, a very simple and quick workaround could be checking the condition and passing the (visually) correct alignment:

```
HStack(
    alignment: text.isEmpty ? .center : .firstTextBaseline //  Conditional alignment
) { ,,, }
```

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately it stops you from typing text after you enter the first character.

Comment: Added another workaround.